# how to ignore number if it is 0 using ternary operator

Tags: java

This is i am trying on Talend Software. where i am writing my expression

This is my data:

```
{
Obj_id: "6",
State_District: "EAST GARO HILLS",
Date: "2020-08-27",
cat1: "0",
cat2: "2",
cat3: "0",
cat4: "4",
cat5: "0",
message: "",
toi: "1900",
vupto: "2200",
color: "2"
}
```

I want to make append all cat column whose value is greater than "0". like in above example i want `2|4`

But i am getting `2|4|`. Means one more extra `|` 
I tried this:

```
(row5.cat1>0 ? row5.cat1 + "|" : "") + (row5.cat2>0 ? row5.cat2 + "|" : "") + (row5.cat3>0 ? row5.cat3 + "|": "") + (row5.cat4>0 ? row5.cat4 + "|": "")+ (row5.cat5>0 ? row5.cat5 + "|": "")
```

Comment: You are appending "|" at the end of the value you return when it's greater than 0, so obviously you're gonna have a "|" as the last character. You can always remove it in a number of ways (`substring()` *et al.*)

Comment: Why not do the following: a) collect all strings into an array or list, b) build a stream of the data in a) and filter everything you don't want and c) join the elements using `collect(Collectors.joining(...))`.

Comment: Btw, `row5.cat1>0` can't work in Java if `cat1` is a string and even it it would the string `"0"` would have a value greater than 0 - unless you're talking JavaScript.

Comment: @Thomas I am writing above expression in Talend software which supports java

Comment: Well, even if Talend _supports_ Java the code that you've posted _is not_ Java, at least not if combined with the data you've shared. It might be translated to Java but then it's hard to tell what will be supported. Are you able to build streams, e.g. do something like `Stream.of(row5.cat1, row5.cat2, ...).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty() && !s.equals("0")).collect(Collectors.joining("|"));`?

Comment: @Thomas getting Collectors cannot be resolved error

Comment: Well, you didn't provide any more information on what's actually supported so it's hard to make suggestions that work for you. You could always go for removing any trailing pipe symbols if that's supported. Which version of Java is supported by the version of Talend you're using?

Comment: @Thomas java version "1.8.0_251"

Comment: So `Collectors` should be available but you also need to _import_ that class. Note that you might want to grab a Java tutorial and get a firm grasp on the basics before diving head first into more complex topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question has nothing to do with your problem.

Any time you add a number (a number is `> 0`) you literally wrote: Put the number in the string, and then a bar. Thus, obviously, the end result will be in the format `2|3|4|5|` - some amount of numbers, and all of them, including the last one, ending in a |.

There are many ways to solve this. An easy way is to lop off a trailing bar:

```
if (str.endsWith("|")) str = str.substring(0, str.length() -1);
```

alternatively, rewrite your code to turn it into a stream of numbers, and then use the 'joining' collector, that'd be a bit more modern.

Comment: I am trying this on Talend software which supports java

Comment: Your comment has nothing to do with either the problem or this answer. Are we even speaking the same language?

Comment: I am not understanding. I am new in java